# Passing Variables Between Components In React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background**

I am trying to pass a `css class` name in a `variable` called `styling` to my `className` on the `tr` element. I think my problem here is that I have yet to grasp the concept of `props`.

Basically I have a `component` written in `ES6` and I want to change the `css class` of a `tr` based on the value of the `child td`.

**Problem**

With my current code I get

> styling not defined

But this does `console.log` all of the appropriate `css class` out so I know everything is good minus the actual `class` being added to `className` of the `tr` tag. For some reason it is not passing the variable inside from `componentDidMount` to `render`.

**Question**

Please explain to me how to pass `variables` throughout my `React.js` `component / components`?

**Example**

```
    class TableDisplay extends React.Component{
                    constructor(props) {
                    super(props);
                }
                componentDidMount() {
                    var styling = " ";
                var tCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
                for (var i = 0; i < tCells.length; i++) {
                        if(tCells[i].innerHTML == "Approved") {
                        console.log("bg-success");
                        styling = "bg-success";
                    } else if (tCells[i].innerHTML == "Denied") {
                        console.log("bg-danger");
                        styling = "bg-danger"; 
                    } else {
                        console.log("bg-plain");
                        styling = "bg-plain";
                    }
                }
                }
            render() {
                return <div><table className="table">
                        <tr className="seperate"><td>Title</td><td>Status</td><td>Created</td><td>Updated</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
                      {Object.keys(requests).map(function(key) {
// Problem appears to be here   
                           return <tr className={styling}>
                                <td>{requests[key].title}</td>
                                <td>{requests[key].status}</td>
                                <td>{requests[key].created_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
                                <td>{requests[key].updated_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
                                <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
                              </tr>;

                                        })}
                    </table>
                   </div>;
           }
    }
```

**What I Have Tried**

I did think this could be a scope or closure issue. So I have tried.

*Global*

Making styling a global variable. That did not work.

*This*

Tried to use this.styling. That did not work either.

*Moved Inside Render*

I moved the loop inside render. When I did that it added the styling variable to the `className` but only the first initial declaration of `styling = " ";`. So basically it just made every `tr` have a space for the `className`.

Comment: Does your "Approved" and "Denied" text comes from requests[key].status or requests[key].title? If so have you tried moving it inside the render function but comparing with those variables instead of innerHTML?

Comment: I have tried moving it. At the bottom of my question I explain the outcome. Basically if I remove styling from the className it runs the app and it outputs all the correct data to the console. But when I move the loop inside render it just adds a space in the className spot for every tr tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "Approved" and "Denied" text is from `requests[key].status`. can't you just do something like this:

```
{Object.keys(requests).map(function(key) {  
    let styling = "bg-plain";

    if (requests[key].status === "Approved") {
        styling = "bg-success";
    } else if (requests[key].status === "Denied") {
        styling = "bg-danger";
    }

    return <tr className={styling}>
        <td>{requests[key].title}</td>
        <td>{requests[key].status}</td>
        <td>{requests[key].created_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
        <td>{requests[key].updated_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
        <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>;

})}
```

Comment: Thanks lol. Jesus man. I'm spending so much time trying to figure out how react's scope works I glazed right over the obvious.

Comment: I must say though. I am still worried why I cant get scope or props to work. If you have any input into that let me know.

Comment: @wuno From your "Example Based On Answer" edit. I can see why `this.state.styling` isn't defined. Since you are not using the ES6 arrow function as callback, your `this` variable isn't in the outer scope. From ES5, people like to have `var self = this` outside then use `self.state.foo` in the callback. Maybe you should take a look at this: http://jsrocks.org/2014/10/arrow-functions-and-their-scope/ for this beautiful arrow functions.

Comment: Ok awesome thanks a lot man! So you mean I should of had an arrow function inside componentDidMount?? WOuld you mind showing me what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [state](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html) in your component so that you can access these variables that are modified at different times during the component's [lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html).

When you create `TableDisplay` set the initial state in the constructor like so:

```
class TableDisplay extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {styling: ""};
  }
```

and based on the conditional in your `componentDidMount` function above change this state by using the `setState` function like so:

```
this.setState({ styling: "what ever you want to change it to"});
```

and access this state by using `this.state.styling` in your `render` function like so:

```
<tr className={this.state.styling}>
```

The reason your `render` function couldn't use the `styling` variable because it's not in the same scope. Once `componentDidMount` was done running, the variable `styling` disappeared. So React's state allows you to access variables throughout your component.

Comment: I updated my question using your explanation. Please look at the bottom of my question and tell me if I am doing what you suggested. I am gettting state is not defined